# Button only changes color after touching

Tags: java, android, button

i use

```
 buttonled1.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

in a function to change the color of a button.
When i first call the function in onCreate() method it works just fine, and the button is created with the color i want.

But when i call in the activity the same function which changes the color of the button again, i have to touch the button to see the color changing.. somehow color changing happens when i want it, but to make it visible i have to touch the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should call `buttonled1.invalidate()` after setting colorfilter.